# Unable to use Simple Injector for DI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm new to using DI and ASP.NET and I'm having a hard time getting Simple Injector to work. I've added SimpleInjector 3.1.5 as a reference using NuGet. Here is what I have so far:

Global.asax.cs:

```
...
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc;
...
protected void Application_Start()
{
        Database.SetInitializer<ProductContext>(new ProductInitializer());
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        container.Register<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

        container.Verify();
}
```

Main controller:

```
...
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    private ProductRepository productRepo;

    public DefaultController(ProductRepository pr)
    {
        this.productRepo = pr;
    }
...
```

Product Repository class:

```
...
public class ProductRepository:IProductRepository
{
    private ProductContext db;

    public ProductRepository(ProductContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Products.ToList();
    }
...
```

When I try to run my program, I get this error:

> The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>
> -[Lifestyle Mismatch] ProductRepository (Web Request) depends on ProductContext (Transient).
>
> -[Short Circuited Dependency] DefaultController might incorrectly depend on unregistered type ProductRepository (Transient) instead of IProductRepository (Web Request).
>
> -[Disposable Transient Component] ProductContext is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>
> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for IProductRepository (Web Request) maps to the same implementation (ProductRepository) as the registration for ProductRepository (Transient) does, but the registration maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance.
>
> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for ProductRepository (Transient) maps to the same implementation (ProductRepository) as the registration for IProductRepository (Web Request) does, but the registration maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve to a different instance.
>
> See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.

Comment: Did you include the Simple Injector NuGet packages for integration with Web API and MVC? It seems you haven't.

Comment: @Steven: When trying to install the package for integration  with Web API, I get this error:

'SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping' already has a dependency for 'SimpleInjector'

Comment: You also have a minor issue, you should the Interface when using DI `public DefaultController(IProductRepository pr)`

Comment: @OrelEraki That's the beauty of Simple Injector: It will warn about this when you call `Verify`. But very sharp observation though.

Comment: @ray9209 the c# compiler doesn't lie; you are missing those assemblies. NuGet probably screwed up; that happens all the time. Just create a fresh .NET 4.5 project and start over.

Comment: @Steven: I was using .NET version 4.0 instead of 4.5, that was causing the error. But now I'm getting a runtime error (I updated the question).

Comment: @ray9209 Please read the documentation that the error message refers to: https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics. It explains why you are getting those errors and how to fix them. If you have any questions after reading that, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please update you Simple Injector to latest version and check updated documentation:

ASP.NET Core: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html
ASP.NET MVC: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html

Or select your integration option from left sidebar menu